# How can I achieve IF ALL ELSE, in Decision Table?

Tags: drools

Drools 5.4
I have a decision table that sets values in the BlueReport object based on Channel Name attribute.  Everything works, except if a Channel name contains an unknown channel for which we don't have mappings, we need to set the values to indicate this condition.   The picture below should illustrate this more clearly, I'm sure.   Here is what we want:

[image]

How can we achieve the "ALL OTHERS" default condition?!

I've evolved my spreadsheet rules to this now:
[image: Decision Table 2]

In this version of DT above, I have left B15 blank, and then I have added a new condition on C15 which checks the auditRule field for presence of string variable "DIV".   I don't know if I have the right syntax for it in C9?!   The ruleAudit field is update everytime there is a match for Channel Name (F11 - F15).   Therefore, absence of DIV rule name, would indicate that there is no match to any of the patterns on B11 - B14.  What do you think?!

Comment: Check the documentation on "Spread Sheet Syntax", Subsection "Rule Set Entries", SEQUENTIAL.

Comment: I looked at the definition of SEQUENTIAL in the documentation as you suggested, perhaps I didn't make my example clear enough.   In my example "All Other values..." is not a literal string....   it means any string value other than the list of entries above.   There are 185 valid channels.   If any other value other than the 185 valid ones come across we need to flag that record as invalid (Orig Country = 999).

Comment: Are we out of luck with this important feature?!  We found this:  https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-2068

Comment: If you omit an entry in B15, the constraint with channel_name should not be added to the last rule. The problem is that you'd have to inhibit firing by adding another constraint, e.g. country being null. To make this work. `update`must be called on the fact after calling the setters.

Comment: Most of the uses of spreadsheet are ill-advised. Either it generates an huge number of rules, or the "otherwise" case needs handling etc. Consider defining a parameter fact with the data in rows like 11 to 14 and match these _with a single rule_ to a BlueReport. Adding a low-salience rule for row 15 is a cinch. (You still can use spreadsheets for data entry and generate the parameter facts from them. 20 lines of code, maybe.)

Comment: I've added Table 2 - please help me with syntax in C9 (string field contains a value).

Answer (score 0):

Add a new condition column again with declaration for blueReport and set this condition
 `channel_name!=$1 || channel_name!=$2 ||channel_name!=$3 || channel_name!=$4` 
New Condition's value field must be empty for the first four records except these values like `ChannelName1,ChannelName2,ChannelName3,ChannelName4` in "ALL OTHERS" row.  Though this isn't the standard solution try this workaround to check

Comment: I see what you mean, but we have 148 unique channel names.... which gets to be cumbersome with the proposed alternative.   Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I think [the post](http://drools-moved.46999.n3.nabble.com/Sequential-and-Decision-Tables-td4030631.html) can help you. It means you should not only declare `sequential` in the `RuleSet`, but also declare `PRIORITY` in `RuleTable` that the rules will be called according to the value of `PRIORITY`.